# Multiple Pin-it button on the same page

Tags: javascript, button, pinterest

I created a Pinterest button with the following code on an article:

```
<a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark"  data-pin-color="red"></a>
```

of course I've got the JS too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

and it works fine by itself, but if I want to add a second button at the end of the article it just doesn't work. The second button doesn't change and stays as a link instead of an iframe.

Is this even possible or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each button you create, add an ID at the end of the link :

```
 <a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/0" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark"  data-pin-color="red"></a>
 <a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/1" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark"  data-pin-color="red"></a>
 <a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/2" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark"  data-pin-color="red"></a>...
```

Comment: I'm sad it did'nt. Could you try with 'data-pin-id' ? https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/pin-it/

Comment: I've made a fiddlejs and find out that it works fine with your first code, I must have something else that block the second button

Comment: Is the second pin button always present on the page or added dynamically ?

Comment: It is always, there is one on the top of the article and one on the bottom

Comment: Maybe the pinterest JS can't read the second one if at a different place in the DOM. Did you try to move the second one somewhere else in the page ? Just to test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95251/discussion-between-alteyss-and-leeroy521).

Comment: Thanks for the tips alteyss, I've tried to move it bit by bit to finally found out that I have a tripadvisor JS in the content and this make the second button not appear.

Comment: If it's not actually rendered on the page it won't get picked, otherwise there is no reason that it shouldn't be working. Weird

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="pin-me">Custom HTML Button</span>
<script>
    function pinIt()
        {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
        e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');
        e.setAttribute('src','https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);
        document.body.appendChild(e);
        }


    $('body').on('click', '.pin-me', function(){
            pinIt();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please take a minute to explain your code by making an edit.  At this title this is a code dump.  Please explain why your answer is correct?